# Sequlize with MSSQL bulk insert fails but does not tell at which row or column it failed

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I have an application performing bulk insert in a mssql db via Sequlize. The bulk insertion is failing but does not inform about the exact error. I am catching the error and logging it, but it just says Error. Sharing the code snippet for reference

```
fun(data) {
    try {
         await db.pushData(data)
         res.send("Success")
     }
     catch (err) {
             logger.log("LOGGIN_PUSH_ERROR ",err)
             res.status(500)
             res.send("Push Error " + err)
         }
     });
```

Here is the function performing the insert

```
     pushData : async function(data) {
        await DataTable.bulkCreate(
            data,
        );
    }
```

Logging error is giving the following

`LOGGING_PUSH_ERROR Error`
which is not very descriptive. Is there any way to either log the primary key of the row which caused the bulkinsert to fail or log the column name and value atleast.

Stuck on this for the past 2 days, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you inspect the `err` object by setting a break point or logging its `message` and `stack` props?

Comment: Are you *really*  still using SQL Server 2005? That ran *completely* out of support over **7 years** ago. It is *long* past time you implemented your upgrade path  the next 2 release after 2005 are also now *completely* unsupported, making your upgrade path much harder.

Comment: @Thom A sorry for the confusion, I had mistakenly added wrong tag